# MySQL procedure returns NULL instead of existing data

Tags: mysql, function

I have a table `fanclubs (f_count_m /*count of members*/, id_band /*id of the music band*/)` and I need a function that returns back the `id_band` of the most popular band.

Code:

```
delimiter //

create function best_of (b varchar(2))
returns varchar(6)
begin
    DECLARE b varchar(6);
    SET @b = 
(select s_and_id.id_band from
(select sum(f_count_m), id_band
from fanclubs 
group by id_band
order by f_count_m desc
LIMIT 0,1) as s_and_id);
    return b;
end//

delimiter ;
```

The `select` part returns one `id`. But if I try to use a created function like this:

```
select @best_of
```

or

```
select * from fanclubs where id_band = @best_of
```

I get NULL.

The same with `@b`

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT id_band FROM fanclubs ORDER BY f_count_m DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I haven't tested this (I'm on my tablet), but I think the logic is sound.

Comment: No. Select is OK, (there are many fanclubs of the same band, thats why I use sum(f_count_m)).
Problem is in function. Either I use it wrong or I coded it wrong.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that each band appeared only once, sorry.